# KOTLIN : android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, kotlin-coroutines

I have this code:

```
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val specialMessage = URL("https://finepointmobile.com/api/inventory/v1/message").readText()
        d("Globby", "The message is: $specialMessage")
        lastSavedProduct.text = specialMessage                //line 41
    }
```

But when executing I get the following error:

```
ERROR : android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at com.example.MainActivity$onCreate$2.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:41)
```

I tried changing `lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` to `lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use `Dispatchers.Main`

Comment: tried it, got this : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 3):

If I remember coroutines correctly, then the following should work:

```
lifecycleScope.launch { // runs on Main by default
    val specialMessage = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        URL("https://finepointmobile.com/api/inventory/v1/message").readText()
    } 
    lastSavedProduct.text = specialMessage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Make a CoroutineContext variable
val main: CoroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.Main }
```

then use it in your code

```
lifecycleScope.launch(main) {
    val specialMessage = URL("https://finepointmobile.com/api/inventory/v1/message").readText()
    d("Globby", "The message is: $specialMessage")
    lastSavedProduct.text = specialMessage //line 41
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the lazy ref instead of just using Dispatchers.Main directly?